# Stopping a python thread running an Infinite Loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python programming. I am trying to make a GUI with stoppable threads. 
I borrowed some code from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
```

I have function which creates a thread for another function in another class that runs an infinite loop.

```
class MyClass :

    def clicked_practice(self):

        self.practicethread = MyThread(target=self.infinite_loop_method)
        self.practicethread.start()

    def infinite_loop_method()
        while True :
            // Do something


    #This doesn't seem to work and I am still stuck in the loop

    def infinite_stop(self)
        if self.practicethread.isAlive():
        self.practicethread.stop()
```

I want to create a method to stop this thread .
What's happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you missed the **'The thread itself has to check regularly for the stopped() condition'** bit of that documentation.

Your thread needs to run like this:

```
while not self.stopped():
    # do stuff
```

rather than `while true`. Note that it is still only going to exit at the 'start' of a loop, when it checks the condition. If whatever is in that loop is long-running, that may cause unexpected delays.

Comment: Worse yet, some people do this: `while True: \n\t if not threadObject.stopped():`.
I was pretty shocked the first time I saw someone waste a **whole indentation level** just for that.

Answer (score -2):

```py
import threading
import time
class MultiThreading:

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.started = True
    def threaded_program(self):
        while self.started:
            print("running")
            # time.sleep(10)
    def run(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded_program, args=())
        self.thread.start()
    def stop(self):
        self.started = False
        self.thread.join()
```

Comment: While correct in principle, this is missing an explanation. Worse, the semantics are confusing: `started` is set `True`, before `run()` is executed; `thread` is set to `None` in the constructor instead of the `Thread()` being created there; `started` should be called `running` (as is evident by the print argument).