# Stopping a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way in python to stop a thread? I have a gui with a method which plays 10 second audio files and sends information to GUI window continuously

I am Multithreading because I dont want the GUI to freeze while my files play. I can stop  the thread with my current code but takes a while

My code looks something like this :

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
   """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()


 class Myplayer: 

   // GUI CODE


    def play_button(self, widget):
        self.mythread = MyThread(target=self.practice)
        self.mythread.start()

    def stop_button(self, widget):
         if self.mythead.IsAlive:
            self.self.stop()



    def mplayer(self):
        while not self.mythread.stopped:
        gobject.idle_add(self.insert_text, "\nPlaying a new file")
        subprocess.call(["timidity", "myfile.mid"])
```

Comment: I believe that only a thread can stop itself. You can, however, set a global variable for hat thread to continuously check, which will tell it to stop.

Comment: What GUI system are you using? Python threads are limited by the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) meaning only one thread is ever actually running at a time. If your GUI thread is maintained inside the main Python thread, then it's likely going to freeze while another python thread has access to the GIL.

Comment: *"I can stop the thread with my current code but takes a while."* It's probably taking a while because you're doing something blocking in your `while` loop, which means you wait for whatever blocking operation is running to finish before checking the `stopped` property. Can you share what's going on in the while loop?

Comment: @dano Indeed. As I warned the OP in their other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843193/stopping-a-python-thread-running-an-infinite-loop/24843260#24843260), the thread only stops at the start of a new loop.

Comment: @dano Yes. I am using a `subprocess.call` to a midi player and that's the blocking operation. However, I can't use `Popen` either.

Comment: @AdaXu Is that `while` loop code you're showing actually occuring in `MyThread.run`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to interrupt your midi file while it's playing if your thread is stopped, you can stop the thread more quickly by using `Popen` instead of `call`, and then waiting in a loop for either the process to finish, or for the stop request to come in:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
   """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
           gobject.idle_add(self.insert_text, "\nPlaying a new file")
           p = subprocess.Popen(["timidity", "myfile.mid"])
           while p.poll() is None: # This will loop until the process has exited.
               if self.stopped:
                   # Someone set the stop flag. Kill the process and exit
                   p.terminate()
                   p.join()
                   return
               time.sleep(.1) # Sleep briefly so we don't hog CPU cycles
```

Comment: Wow That wasn't too complicated. Thanks a lot

Comment: In fact, using ``pOpen`` actually removes the need for a ``thread`` in the first place (if calling ``pOpen`` is all it's doing). It's opening a separate child process. You can simply store the returned value somewhere and do the exact same thing directly from the GUI thread to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  We start a single thread which does all the work.  After two seconds, we tell it to die by setting the shared `Event` flag.

The worker thread generally runs in a loop, doing a little processing, then checking the flag.  If it's set, then it exits, otherwise the thread does some more work.

### source

```
import time
from threading import *

class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, die_flag, *args, **kw):
        super(WorkerThread,self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.die_flag = die_flag

    def run(self):
        for num in range(3):
            if self.die_flag.is_set():
                print "{}: bye".format(
                    current_thread().name
                    )
                return
            print "{}: num={}".format(
                current_thread().name, num,
                )
            time.sleep(1)

flag = Event()

WorkerThread(name='whiskey', die_flag=flag).start()
time.sleep(2)

print '\nTELL WORKERS TO DIE'
flag.set()

print '\nWAITING FOR WORKERS'
for thread in enumerate():
    if thread != current_thread():
        print thread.name,
        thread.join()
    print
```

### output

```
whiskey: num=0
whiskey: num=1

TELL WORKERS TO DIE

WAITING FOR WORKERS

whiskey whiskey: bye
```